# adding date to Java util logger fileHandler name

Tags: java, logging, design-patterns, filehandler

Hi I currently have this in my .properties file:

`java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = %h/programName%u%g.log`

I would also like to append a timestamp / username to this so its easy to identify log files does anyone know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the FileHandler methods don't have a % substitution variable for date, my suggestion would be to format a string that includes the date before passing the string to FileHandler.  Something like:

```
String pattern = String.format("%%h/programName%tYmd%%u%%g.log", today);
FileHandler fh = new FileHandler(pattern);
```

Comment: Ah, I missed the properties file part.  That will require a little more thinking.

Comment: Do you have access to programmatically write to the .properties file on program startup?  And is this a program that executes and quits, or something that stays loaded (possibly overnight)?